# Cheap easy and portable instruments

Tags: learning

I am 14 and would like to start playing an instrument. I sing rather a lot in local musicals and in my school choir but am always jealous of those in the orchestra.

it must

1) be easy to learn

- something i can pick up in a year or even less

2) be cheap

- I am only fourteen and on limited funds

3) be quiet

- i live with my parents and brother who get home late most nights. I wouldn't like to disturb their sleep

4) be portable and light

- something i can just carry around with no trouble

5) have a nice sound

- one that can transport you to a magical land, through adventure and back in time for tea.( being British that is important)

6) impressive

- something large or small i can wow my friends and family with.

Comment: @user8890 My vote is for ukulele; in my opinion, it meets all 6 of your requirements.  But for more ideas, read the question that Dom linked to.

Comment: @user8890: See also [What instrument is inexpensive and can can be self taught](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7856/what-instrument-is-inexpensive-and-can-be-self-taught).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of music do you like? That might help you chose. No point in getting a guitar if you really only like symphonic music, and vice versa, no point in learning violin if you only really like heavy metal.

If you're interested in joining an orchestra though, violin might be a good choice.

Personally, I'd say learn keyboard, which you can do by hooking up a > 100$ midi controller to your computer, putting on headphones, and playing with any sound you could ever imagine. Then not only can you buy bigger and better synths (or play other peoples), but you can also learn to play piano.

Comment: Surely keyboard is a bad choice if he wants to play in an orchestra?

Comment: OP said they are jealous of those in orchestra, none of their 6 requirements involve playing in an orchestra.

Comment: The keyboard (and piano) is the most fundamental instrument people should start with when coming into the musical world. However, I agree with ohope5 that you can't play the keyboard (or the piano) in an orchestra. The violin is very popular, and many people start with that as well.

Comment: I can't say for sure that what the OP meant, that was just my reading of it. I do agree that the keyboard is a fundamental instrument to learn though (it was my first).

Comment: Sure, I expanded my answer to reflect if they did want to join an orchestra, than I do agree @ohope5, that the violin would probably be a good choice. They always get the interesting parts!